# Errors in code generated by swagger-codegen with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swagger, swift4, swagger-codegen

I've got a new project where all REST code is generated by swagger-codegen, which I've never used before. Everything seems to work fine except requestBuilder initialisation error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'RequestBuilder<_>.Type' to specified type 'RequestBuilder<MyGeneratedModel>.Type'
```

Request builder:

```
let requestBuilder: RequestBuilder<TimeoutForNextRequestInSeconds>.Type = SwaggerClientAPI.requestBuilderFactory.getBuilder()
```

requestBuilderFactory:

```
open static var requestBuilderFactory: RequestBuilderFactory = AlamofireRequestBuilderFactory()
```

AlamofireRequestBuilderFactory:

```
class AlamofireRequestBuilderFactory: RequestBuilderFactory {
    func getNonDecodableBuilder<T>() -> RequestBuilder<T>.Type {
        return AlamofireRequestBuilder<T>.self
    }

    func getBuilder<T:Decodable>() -> RequestBuilder<T>.Type {
        return AlamofireDecodableRequestBuilder<T>.self
    }
}

public protocol RequestBuilderFactory {
    func getNonDecodableBuilder<T>() -> RequestBuilder<T>.Type            
    func getBuilder<T:Decodable>() -> RequestBuilder<T>.Type
}
```

Any guess what can it be?

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the swagger codegen community can help.

Comment: I've added some related code to my question and created the issue https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7041